# Javascript overrides CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am using on css as in aspx file as below.

```
<link href="../include/_stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and im using one script for highlighting the search text...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../include/search.js"></script>
```

the script consists of following functions...

```
function doHighlight(bodyText, searchTerm, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag) 
{

  if ((!highlightStartTag) || (!highlightEndTag)) {
    highlightStartTag = "<font style='color:blue; background-color:yellow;'>";
    highlightEndTag = "</font>";
  }

  var newText = "";
  var i = -1;
  var lcSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  var lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();

  while (bodyText.length > 0) {
    i = lcBodyText.indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i+1);
    if (i < 0) {
      newText += bodyText;
      bodyText = "";
    } else {
      // skip anything inside an HTML tag
      if (bodyText.lastIndexOf(">", i) >= bodyText.lastIndexOf("<", i)) {
        // skip anything inside a <script> block
        if (lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("/script>", i) >= lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("<script", i)) 
        {
          newText += bodyText.substring(0, i) + highlightStartTag + bodyText.substring(i,searchTerm.length) + highlightEndTag;
          bodyText = bodyText.substring(i + searchTerm.length);
          lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();
          i = -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }  
  return newText;
}

function highlightSearchTerms(searchText, treatAsPhrase, warnOnFailure, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag)
{

  if (treatAsPhrase) {
    searchArray = [searchText];
  } else {
    searchArray = searchText.split(" ");
  }

  if (!document.body || typeof(document.body.innerHTML) == "undefined") {
    if (warnOnFailure) {
      alert("Sorry, for some reason the text of this page is unavailable. Searching will not work.");
    }
    return false;
  }

  var bodyText = document.body.innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
    bodyText = doHighlight(bodyText, searchArray[i], highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag);
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = bodyText;
  return true;
}

//GetQueryString
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_=""; 
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}

function searchString()
{ 
 var defaultText='the page';
 var treatAsPhrase='true';
 var textColor='green';
 var bgColor='pink';
  // This function prompts the user for any words that should
  // be highlighted on this web page
  if (!defaultText) {
    defaultText = "";
  }

  // we can optionally use our own highlight tag values
  if ((!textColor) || (!bgColor)) {
    highlightStartTag = "";
    highlightEndTag = "";
  } else {
    highlightStartTag = "<font style='color:" + textColor + "; background-color:" + bgColor + ";'>";
    highlightEndTag = "</font>";
  }

  if (treatAsPhrase) {
    promptText = "Please enter the phrase you'd like to search for:";
  }else {
    promptText = "Please enter the words you'd like to search for, separated by spaces:";
  }

  var searchText = getQuerystring('keyword');  


  if (!searchText)  {    
    return false;
  }

  return highlightSearchTerms(searchText, treatAsPhrase, true, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag);
}
```

after calling this javascript when the page loads...the CSS stops working....

Please help me.

here my css..

```
    body, td, p, ul {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px}

td.border {border: #666666; border-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; width: 95;}

a:link {  color: #666666; text-decoration: underline}
a:visited {  color: #666666; text-decoration: underline}
a:active {  color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline}
a:hover {  color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline}

a.nav:link { color: #666666; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
a.nav:visited { color: #666666; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
a.nav:active { color: #666666; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
a.nav:hover { color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}


a.close:link { color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline;}
a.close:visited { color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline;}
a.close:active { color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline;}
a.close:hover { color: #CC0033; text-decoration: underline;}


input {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 20px;color:black;
}

input.txtbox {font-size: 10px; border-color:#88ACE0;border-style:solid;height:15px;width:125px;color:black}
input.txtboxSmall {font-size: 10px; border-color:#88ACE0; background-color: #ffffff; width: 100px}

.label{font-size: 12px;color:black;font-weight:normal;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:bold;}


input.button
{
   font-size:11px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-weight:bold;
   width:137px;
   height:21px;
   background: url('../images/roundedge-gray-btn1.gif') center;
   border-style:none;
   color:White;


}
input.smallbutton
{
 font-size:11px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-weight:bold;
   width:71px;
   height:21px;
   background: url('../images/roundedge-gray-btn1.gif') center;
   border-style:none;
   color:White;

}

.list
{

font-family: Arial; 
font-size: 10px; 
font-weight:normal; 
background-color: white;
border-color:#FFCCCC;
border-Style:solid;
height:50px;
width:130px;
color: black; 
font-family:Verdana;
}







input.radio { background: rgb(255,255,255) }

select {  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-color: #ffffff}
select.box {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 8pt; width: 180;}

textarea {  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; width: 290px; background-color: #ffffff}

hr {  color: #cccccc; border-style: dashed}

.tableBorder {  border: #666666; border-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px}

.txt10 {  font-size: 10px}
.txt14 {  font-size: 14px}

.txt_white {  color: #FFFFFF}
.txt_grey {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.txt_greynav {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.txt_grey12 {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold
}
.txt_block {  padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 7px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 7px; line-height: 18px}
td { }.txt10_add {  font-size: 10px; color: #6699cc}
.arial8 {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 8pt}
.arial10 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.add {
    color: #CC0033;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.arial10 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.txtheader {
    color: #990033;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.txthelp {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.txtex {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
pre
{
    color: maroon;
}
H2
{
    color: #cc0033;
}
```

Comment: We stopped using FONT tags last decade. Use a SPAN instead.

Comment: It might also help to post the CSS and HTML

Comment: What is the question here exactly? I don't understand. Can you add more detail about what's wrong?

Comment: im using both script and css, if i call javascript function in aspx page load, css not working

Comment: @vasmay what do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Can you post a live link? Does the style sheet get loaded in Firebug?

Comment: What browsers is this happening on?

Comment: actually that script parsing the css applied text and displaying as normal text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is wrapping portions of text on the page in `<font>` tags.  That change to the DOM is probably causing the selectors used in your CSS stylesheet to no longer apply to the affected text. You have not (yet) posted the CSS, so it's hard to say what exactly is wrong, but (for example) if you have a rule that applies some font characteristics to *everything* (not uncommon), and then those are overridden by other CSS rules for specific elements, then the introduced `<font>` tags might mess that all up.

Another more insidious possibility is that the code is not correctly skipping HTML elements.  If the `<font>` tags end up breaking the overall page DOM structure, then all bets are off and it's no wonder the CSS stops working.